# How to log ssh client connection/command?

Tags: linux, logging, ssh

I would like to know how i could log SSH command lines a user is using on a server. For exemple, if the user Alex on my server is doing the following set of commands :

```
$ cd /tmp
$ touch myfile
$ ssh staff@10.0.0.1
$ ssh staff@10.0.0.2
$ vim anotherfile
$ ssh alex@192.168.0.12
```

I would like to log the ssh commands used on the server in a file which looks like :

```
[2014-07-25 10:10:10] Alex : ssh staff@10.0.0.1
[2014-07-25 10:18:20] Alex : ssh staff@10.0.0.2
[2014-07-25 11:15:10] Alex : ssh alex@192.168.0.12
```

I don't care what he did during his ssh session, i just want to know WHEN and TO WHERE he made a connection to another server.

The user is not using bash and i would like to avoid manipulating .bash_history anyway as the user can modify it.

Any clue on this ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can replace `ssh` your own script and log everything.

1. rename your `/usr/bin/ssh` to `/usr/bin/real-ssh`
2. Create new `/usr/bin/ssh` like this(not tested, just give you an idea)

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/sh
>
> echo [`date`] `whoami` : ssh $*  >> YOUR_LOG_FILE
>
> /usr/bin/real-ssh $*
> ```

Comment: That's a way indeed, but if the user knows this, he could use real-ssh instead... :(

Comment: Yes, he can, unfortunately, I dont know the other ways. may be this question are more suitable at http://serverfault.com. most of system admins are there to help you :).

Comment: Ahah yes ! I'll post my question there too thanks ^^

Comment: I was going to suggest to change permission of /usr/bin/real-ssh to 550 and use sudo in the ssh script to run it, but you actually cannot prevent the users to just put an ssh binary file in their home directory and use it. If you want it secure you must log on the servers (you can centralise logs using rsyslog).